# Program only runs with clang compiler

Tags: c

When I compile this program with the clang compiler and then run it, I get this output:

```
sum = 9
product = 6
sum - product = 6 - 6 = 0
```

and when I compile it with the gcc compiler and run it, the program terminates with a segmentation fault. Why is this?

Another question, why does `*sum` have the value 6 in this part of the code?:

```
printf("sum - product = %d - %d = %d\n",
                          *sum, *product, *sum - *product);
```

Also, why does `*sum - *product` produce the value 0?

Here is the program:

```
/***********************************************************************
* This program will add two numbers and then it will multiply two other
* numbers. Finally, it will subtract the second result from the first
* result.
***********************************************************************/

#include <stdio.h>

int *add(int a, int b) {
    int result = a + b;
    return &result;
}

int *multiply(int p, int q) {
    int result = p * q;
    return &result;
}

int main() {
    int *sum = add(4, 5);
    printf("sum = %d\n", *sum);
    int *product = multiply(2, 3);
    printf("product = %d\n", *product);
    printf("sum - product = %d - %d = %d\n",
                          *sum, *product, *sum - *product);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why does `add` return an `int*` instead of an `int`?

Comment: `return &result;` <-- _ugggggggggggghhh_ - this won't work because inside `add` the `result`  variable is an _automatic_ variable which no-longer-exists when `add` returns, so it is incorrect to return the address-of an automatic (but you can just return an `int` value directly).

Comment: Perhaps a [book](https://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/631266) would help you in your efforts to learn.

Comment: Classic case of undefined behaviour, anything can happen, even apparently working correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Compile using `clang` compiler:

```
# clang prg.c 
prg.c:5:13: warning: address of stack memory associated with local variable 'result' returned [-Wreturn-stack-address]
    return &result;
            ^~~~~~
prg.c:10:13: warning: address of stack memory associated with local variable 'result' returned [-Wreturn-stack-address]
    return &result;
            ^~~~~~
```

Compile using `gcc` compiler:

```
# gcc prg.c 
prg.c: In function 'add':
prg.c:5:12: warning: function returns address of local variable [-Wreturn-local-addr]
     return &result;
            ^~~~~~~
prg.c: In function 'multiply':
prg.c:10:12: warning: function returns address of local variable [-Wreturn-local-addr]
     return &result;
            ^~~~~~~
```

Warnings are there for **some** reason. Don't ignore them.

Variable `result` is a local(automatic) non-static variable and its lifetime is limited to its scope i.e. the block in which it has been declared. Any attempt to access it outside of its lifetime lead to undefined behaviour<sup>1)</sup>.

---

1). An undefined behaviour includes it may execute incorrectly (either crashing or silently generating incorrect results), or it may fortuitously do exactly what the programmer intended.

Answer (score 0):

You're returning pointers to local vars, which gives undefined behavior, as the local vars go away when the function returns, leaving the pointers dangling.

Try enabling warnings.